Some taxonomy term pages don't include all nodes

PHP 8.1.29
10.6.18-MariaDB-cll-lve-log
10.2.6 Drupal core with no PHP customization.
Taxonomy term view is 100% default without changes.

Some taxonomy term pages don't include all nodes; they include no more than I think three nodes (could be three out of 30 or 300).
The website is otherwise working fine with no errors and I didn't find any warning in the database log at /admin/reports/dblog.
How to solve that problem?
